# use withr::with_options to pass shiny.maxRequestSize to a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I dont understand why this code doesn't work as expected :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("option"),
  verbatimTextOutput("option2"),
  actionButton("go","go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$option <- renderText({getOption("repos")})
  output$option2 <- renderText({ getOption("shiny.maxRequestSize") })
}

withr::with_options(list(shiny.maxRequestSize="find_me"), {
  shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
})
```

this app should show "find_me" inside a textouput
do I make a typo? `getOption("shiny.maxRequestSize")` have to be 'find_me', why not?

I certainly can add this option inside the server, but I prefere to use with_option.

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `with_options` works with `runApp` but not with `shinyApp`. I do not know why, but at least, you can use this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("option"),
  verbatimTextOutput("option2"),
  actionButton("go","go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$option <- renderText({getOption("repos")})
  output$option2 <- renderText({ getOption("shiny.maxRequestSize") })
}

withr::with_options(list(shiny.maxRequestSize="find_me"), {
  # shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
  shiny::runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `shinyApp()` alone doesn't run the app. It's when R is printing it to the console that does it.

As such, the code you have is equivalent to (which fails):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("option"),
  verbatimTextOutput("option2"),
  actionButton("go","go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$option <- renderText({getOption("repos")})
  output$option2 <- renderText({ getOption("shiny.maxRequestSize") })
}

app <- withr::with_options(list(shiny.maxRequestSize="find_me"), {
  shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
})

print(app)
```

The solution is to wrap/pipe it on a `shiny::runApp()` or `print()` function.

```r
withr::with_options(list(shiny.maxRequestSize="find_me"), {
  shiny::runApp(shiny::shinyApp(ui, server))
})
```